# How to change the drop zone in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So, I have two problems:

1. Why is this `});//]]>` at the top of the page in jsfiddle.
2. Second, the real issue, How can I change the drop zone of the jQuery sortable object to reflect where the mouse is.  So what I mean is, It should not matter where you drag the sortable from (extreme top left corner or bottom right) but instead only rely on if the mouse is over `tab1` or `tab2` to be dropped.

Currently, the center of the sortable has to be over `tab1` or `tab2`.

```
var $tab_items = $("ul:first li", $tabs).droppable({
    accept: ".connectedSortable li",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var $item = $(this);
        var $list = $($item.find("a").attr("href"))
            .find(".connectedSortable");

        ui.draggable.hide("slow", function () {
            $tabs.tabs("select", $tab_items.index($item));
            $(this).appendTo($list).show("slow");
        });
    }
});
```

I am fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery.  I think that `drop: function( event, ui ) {` is definitely where i should be looking. Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/justinmvail/LARnD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('selector').droppable({ tolerance: "pointer", ...
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LARnD/2/)

You'll want to set the [`tolerance`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance) option for `draggable`.

The script tags in the fiddle caused the strange characters.